# load csv and delete \r\n python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, load-csv

I can not load my csv with pandas correctly, I have some matrices and vectors but I get a (\ r \ n) for example i tried this:

```
test = pd.read_csv('test.csv',sep='\t',index_col=0)
test.head()
```

and i get this:

```
test['image_gray'][0]
```

> > '[[0.4297102  0.4297102  0.42578863 ... 0.37573176 0.34549804 0.30628235]\r\n [0.41794549 0.41402392 0.40618078 ... 0.37573176 0.34549804 0.30628235]\r\n [0.39833765 0.39441608 0.38151255 ... 0.3718102  0.34549804 0.30628235]\r\n ...\r\n [0.03164039 0.01987569 0.01763569 ... 0.55161137 0.55553294 0.55496745]\r\n [0.03385765 0.02771882 0.01763569 ... 0.55945451 0.56281059 0.56281059]\r\n [0.03777922 0.02771882 0.01763569 ... 0.56281059 0.56673216 0.57065373]]'

i don't want (\r\n) i have the same proble in others columns of my dataframe.

¿What could i do ?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using windows. then try passing the `os.linesep` as the `lineterminator` to `read_csv`

```
pd.read_csv('test.csv', sep='\t', sep='\t', lineterminator=os.linesep)
```

But the file you have might be malformed with `\r\n\n`. Check that.

Comment: this gives me an error:
InvalidConfigError: Invalid client secrets file ('Error opening file', 'client_secrets.json', 'No such file or directory', 2)

I created the initial dataframe and it was correct, and i save it with this code:
>>dataframeall.to_csv("path//test.csv", sep='\t')